# insert collection of data into sql server columns with storedprocedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

i'm begginer in sql server

i want to insert collection of data into the column in stored procedure

i want pass data from c# like this `(100,'3,5,4,2,9')` and insert to the column like this

```
ID   Number

100    3
100    5
100    4
100    2
100    9
```

My procedure code

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Number]
    @Number CHAR(10),
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        INSERT INTO NumbersTbl
            VALUES(@Number)
        SELECT 1        
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        EXEC SQLError
        SELECT -1
    END CATCH
END
```

how i can do it?

thank you

Comment: `insert into NumbersTbl values (100,'1'),(100,'2'),(100,'3');`

Comment: @tinka i want pass data from c#,my pass data like this (100,'3,5,4,2,9')

Comment: Will it always be in that form? `(Col1value,'Col2values.......')`, or will you sometimes get multiple Col1values?

Comment: @Samcd yes, it will always be in that form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Procedure Definition

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Number]
    @Value  INT,
    @Number Varchar(100),
    @Sucecc BIT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;
   DECLARE @xml xml;
    BEGIN TRY

       SET @xml = cast(('<X>'+replace(@Number,',' ,'</X><X>')+'</X>') as xml)

        INSERT INTO NumbersTbl (Column1 , Column2)
        SELECT @Value,  N.value('.', 'varchar(100)') as value 
        FROM @xml.nodes('X') as T(N)

        SET @Sucecc = 1;        
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        EXEC SQLError
        SET @Sucecc = 0;
    END CATCH
END
```

### Call Procedure

```
DECLARE @Result BIT;
Exec [dbo].[Number] @Value = 100
                   ,@Number = '3,5,4,2,9'
                   ,@Sucecc = @Result OUTPUT
```

Answer (score 0):

First you can create the special function to parse input numbers:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.splitstring ( @stringToSplit VARCHAR(MAX) )
RETURNS
 @returnList TABLE ([Numbers] [nvarchar] (500))
AS
BEGIN

 DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(255)
 DECLARE @pos INT

 WHILE CHARINDEX(',', @stringToSplit) > 0
 BEGIN
  SELECT @pos  = CHARINDEX(',', @stringToSplit)  
  SELECT @name = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, 1, @pos-1)

  INSERT INTO @returnList 
  SELECT @name

  SELECT @stringToSplit = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, @pos+1, LEN(@stringToSplit)-@pos)
 END

 INSERT INTO @returnList
 SELECT @stringToSplit

 RETURN
END
```

And then edit your procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Number]
        @ID     INT,
        @Number VARCHAR(MAX)

    AS
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRY

          INSERT INTO NumbersTbl(ID, Number)
          SELECT @ID, Numbers
          FROM dbo.splitstring(@Number)  

        END TRY    
        BEGIN CATCH    
            EXEC SQLError    
            SELECT -1    
        END CATCH    
    END
```

Call: `EXEC Number 100,'3,5,4,2,9'`

Comment: There are much better versions of Split function out there specially the ones with XML, the version of split function you have used is not very efficient :) plus it can be done without the function have a look at my answer

Comment: Thanks. I always use this function. You interested me. I will seek information about better versions of Split function. :-)